# How can I format a local mobile phone number to a international one?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, formatting, phone-number

I am using the contact_service package for flutter to retrieve contacts from a device. But I noticed that when I look at the `_contacts[index].phones` it holds either mobile or other. I only take the contacts that have a mobiel phone number. But then when I look at the phonenumbers I see that they are all have a different format.

```
+31XXXXXXXX
+31 6 XXXXXXXX
06-XXXXXXXX
06 XXXXXXXX
6 XXXXXXXX
(045) XXXXXXXX
045 XXXXXXXX
```

**Side Note:** I am working on a android simulator with a google account

I would prefer to have them all with a country code so that I can compare them with my firebase auth phonenumber. So my question is what do I do?

Do I  format the contact list phonenumber on the client side? Or do I just send it and use a cloud function to somehow figure it out? And how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I format the contact list phonenumber on the client side?
>
> <strike>Or do I just send it and use a cloud function to somehow figure it out?</strike>

Client side - a good idea. Especially given the fact that just a local phone number is not enough. You also need to guess the country. And that's easier on the client side where you have more context. It's also better for performance.

> And how do I do that?

Probably, that's what you're looking for:

1. https://github.com/google/libphonenumber
2. https://pub.dev/packages/phone_number#-example-tab-

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following:

1. Know what country your client is from.
2. Save the number as is with the name
3. Try to guess the country code through a process and save all versions
4. Do search using all versions

Trying to guess the correct number:

- if it starts with + => it's good
- else if it starts with 00 => replace 00 with +
- else use the user's country code, in this case check if the contact name corresponds to other searched user
- Or ask the user: do you know this person?

[You can find countries key code here](https://countrycode.org)

I hope this helps,
Good luck.